# Fade animation not work for layer-backed views under OS X 10.6/7

Tags: cocoa, animation

I have fade-in animation issue: If in the same method I create a layer-backed view and add it to other view, and then animate it alpha value: `[[view animator] setAlphaValue:alphaValue];` view appears without animation. But, if in one method, for example `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` I create a layer-backed view and add it to other view and in another perform animation, for example in button action method, all works fine.  For fade-out animation all works fine. I found this issue under 10.6 and 10.7 and don't know how to fix it. Maybe someone know what happens?

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/karamazov/views-opacity-animation/src) a sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in [this Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/BasicCocoaAnimations/Introduction/Intro.html). If your views are layer backed you should use the animator to add/remove subviews. 
`[[window.contentView animator] addSubview:someView];`